# Creating Code to read another Streams Uptime and saving timestamp for quick find

Tags: mirc, uptime

Hey guys I'm trying to figure out a code in mirc that will allow me to access the uptime command in the stream I mod for so I can save it to quickly find parts of stream for Highlights and gifs and whatnot.

So far I have tried something like this,

```
on *:Text:!SaveThis:#: {
  if ($nick isOp #) { msg $nick # Timestamp Saved! }
  else { msg # $nick Sorry you cannot use this command }
```

but the code is messed up somewhere. Also when using this it doesn't recognize m as Op status in that Channel. Does anyone have any ideas or know how to do this? I've searched all over the net and cannot find anything on this. Thank you!

Comment: You probably have some `on text` code before that ignoring this one, or you have errors on the lines above this code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing an closing bracket
2. Use `if ($nick isop $chan)`

Comment: Thanks i fixed the closing bracket and added the $chan but it is still saying i am not allowed to use the command. I am mod in the channel but it isnt reading me as one. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Script is working fine for me, must be something wrong at your end.

Comment: ok cool thanks for letting me know it works. ill work on trying to figure out why its not for me.